# Can Ruby Eventmachine be used without Newline character in the receiving data

Tags: ruby, newline, eventmachine

I am using EventMachine as a open_datagram_socket and want to know if it is possible to use it without the receiving data to contain a "\n" character at the end.

Is this the default behaviour or can it be set to receive raw buffers as the data comes in?

I can't find anything regarding this around this when EventMachine is used as a TCP or UDP server, there are a lot of information when it is used as a key board catcher...

Comment: Can you send a code sample that provokes this?